# aligning zero line in echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts

normally I would have some full-blwn code to post with my questions but this is a very generic question... I have create a chart with two y-axis on echarts through `yAxis: [{name:'abc', type:'value'},{name:'xyz',type:'value'}]`. both axes might have data that goes to negative, but the second axis doesn't always have negative numbers. I would like both axes' 0 value line to align at the same level at all times. As the range of both axes individually might vary greatly depending on the dataset supplied, I wouldn't want to manually set the ranges for them and would like to rely on echarts built-in capability to decide on an appropriate range as long as the zero line is aligned. is this possible at all? thanks in advance